# Cannot Parse Paypal "notify_url" Data Into an Associative Array (PHP)

Tags: php, json, paypal

I am setting up a Paypal sandbox. Everything works fine. When the transaction is done, paypal POSTS some data to my "notify_url" page (which I've named process-payment.php).

Now, when I post:

```
$array = $_POST;
$encodedString = json_decode($array);
```

Now, I can PUT that encoded string in the database, and it looks like:

```
{"mc_gross":"10.00","protection_eligibility":"Eligible",
"address_status":"confirmed","payer_id"}
```

Now, my big question is, how can I get THAT (^^^) into an associative array, where I can store those values in a database that records the transaction? Thank you so much for your help in advance! I've already tried:

```
    $pp_array = file_get_contents('php://input');

    $arrayDump = json_encode($pp_array);

    $pp_array = json_decode($pp_array, true);
```

Which, obviously, didn't work. So, kinda hoping someone can give me a little tutelage here!

Comment: " obviously, didn't work." can mean a lot. Dou you get an error message? What is the output? Also your question is not specifically Paypal related (not about retrieving the data and not about storing the data).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `json_decode` on an bad array because your `payer_id` is NULL. Consider filling or removing it. This is a working example with a filled `payer_id`:

```
$json = '{"mc_gross":"10.00","protection_eligibility":"Eligible", "address_status":"confirmed","payer_id":"2"}';
$json_asoc = (json_decode($json, true));
print $json_asoc['mc_gross']; // 10
```

For details see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out that the code I used to make it work was this:

```
    $array = $_POST;

    $arrayDump = json_encode($array);

    file_put_contents('payment-record.txt', $arrayDump);

    $fileContents = file_get_contents('payment-record.txt');

    $pp_array = json_decode($fileContents, true);
```

That gave me a workable array. Not sure why I had to write it first, but there you go.

Comment: That is not very nice. It probably only worked because, when reading the file, `file_get_contents` is assigning an empty string to the NULL parameter .